# LINQ expression String.Contains doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, kendo-grid, contains

I have a Kendo Grid, which has to be filtered by a column. It works fine with IsEqualTo, IsNotEqualTo, StartsWith and EndsWith cases but not with Contains or DoesNotContain cases.

My code is like:

```
switch (ertesitettDescriptor.Operator)
{
    case FilterOperator.IsEqualTo:
         res = res.Where(m => m.ErtesitendoSzerv.Nev.ToLower() == filterValue.ToLower());
         break;
    case FilterOperator.IsNotEqualTo:
         res = res.Where(m => !(m.ErtesitendoSzerv.Nev.ToLower() == filterValue.ToLower()));
         break;
    case FilterOperator.Contains:
         res = res.Where(m => m.ErtesitendoSzerv.Nev.ToLower().Contains(filterValue.ToLower()));
         break;
    case FilterOperator.DoesNotContain:
         res = res.Where(m => !(m.ErtesitendoSzerv.Nev.ToLower().Contains(filterValue.ToLower())));
         break;
    case FilterOperator.StartsWith:
         res = res.Where(m => (m.ErtesitendoSzerv.Nev.ToLower().StartsWith(filterValue.ToLower())));
         break;
    case FilterOperator.EndsWith:
         res = res.Where(m => (m.ErtesitendoSzerv.Nev.ToLower().EndsWith(filterValue.ToLower())));
         break;
    default:
         return new JavaScriptResult { Script = "kendo.alert('A szűrés módja nem támogatott!')" };
}
```

All works fine, so the values are ok, but the `.Contains` method doesn't give back any records.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it cause an exception to be thrown? Does it leave out records you think should be included? Does it include records you think should be excluded? Does it filter correctly, but client-side instead of server-side?

Comment: Both your title and tags are misleading. What you have used is a LINQ not Entity Framework.

Comment: Sorry for that I've updated.

I mean it doesn't give back any records. There must be some, because with the other four it shows them but not with Contains.

Comment: OT most of those methods have an overload with a StringComparison parameter - then you don't need all those .ToLower()s. For == there is string.Equals

Comment: Is your input a culture specific string? Then `string.compare` does not support culture-sensitive comparison. You can create your own extension method for comparison. Refer here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_Contains_System_String_

Comment: It works properly after removing all ToLowers. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LINQ to SQL, it automatically ignores case sensitivity. You can achieve results without converting it to lowercase or uppercase.

```
res = res.Where(m => !(m.ErtesitendoSzerv.Nev.Contains(filterValue)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just took the liberty of cleaning up the code alittle, and added `StringComparison` to your filtering. i assume the StringComparison solves your issue, as you no longer need to use ToLower().

```
StringComparison comp = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

switch (ertesitettDescriptor.Operator)
{
    case FilterOperator.IsEqualTo:
         res = res.Where(m => m.ErtesitendoSzerv.Nev.Equals(filterValue, comp);
         break;
    case FilterOperator.IsNotEqualTo:
         res = res.Where(m => !m.ErtesitendoSzerv.Nev.Equals(filterValue, comp);
         break;
    case FilterOperator.Contains:
         res = res.Where(m => m.ErtesitendoSzerv.Nev.Contains(filterValue, comp));
         break;
    case FilterOperator.DoesNotContain:
         res = res.Where(m => !m.ErtesitendoSzerv.Nev.Contains(filterValue, comp));
         break;
    case FilterOperator.StartsWith:
         res = res.Where(m => m.ErtesitendoSzerv.Nev.StartsWith(filterValue, comp));
         break;
    case FilterOperator.EndsWith:
         res = res.Where(m => m.ErtesitendoSzerv.Nev.EndsWith(filterValue, comp));
         break;
    default:
         return new JavaScriptResult { Script = "kendo.alert('A szűrés módja nem támogatott!')" };
}
```